# How to prevent 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll' with an empty textbox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have just programmed a very simple program to help me work out the amount of carbohydrate per meal (I have diabetes) and my issue is I get a `System.FormatException` when one of my textboxes are empty.

How may I prevent this please ?

My code (using a form consisting of 3 textboxes; 2 of which require input from me and a third which shows the result of a simple equation).

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form()
    {
        tbCCG.TextChanged += TextBoxChanged;
        tbCTG.TextChanged += TextBoxChanged;
    }


    private void TextBoxChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        decimal carbsT;
        decimal carbsPerC = Convert.ToDecimal(tbCCG.Text);
        decimal totCarbs = Convert.ToDecimal(tbCTG.Text);
        carbsT = carbsPerC / 100 * totCarbs;
        tbTC.Text = carbsT.ToString("###,###.00");
    }     
}
```

Comment: What about... `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbCCG.Text)) { ... }` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can verify the text in your text boxes

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tbCCG.Text))
    tbCCG.Text = "0";

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tbCTG.Text))
    tbCTG.Text = "0";

decimal carbsPerC = Convert.ToDecimal(tbCCG.Text);
decimal totCarbs = Convert.ToDecimal(tbCTG.Text);
```

but if you don't have any kind of restrictions on your text box try using `decimal.TryParse`.

Comment: Of course if someone types "ABC" we are back again at the FormatException

Comment: yes, you can also use `decimal.TryParse` method. @Steve

Comment: Perhaps you should extend your answer because as is it doesn't solve the problem of users typing bad inputs

Comment: I've edited that 14 seconds before your comment :D @Steve